# jQuery UI 1.8.18 Is it possible to change individual tab color?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a jQuery UI 1.8.18 tab that is data driven. There are 5 possible tabs but each tab only shows up if the data for it is available. This is working just fine. I now have a request for one of these tabs to be highlighted if it does show up. They would like the tab itself (not the tab area) to be a different color than the rest of the tabs. I cannot find anything on this. Is this possible?

Comment: can you share the html markup

Comment: In the abstract sense, what you want is to change the background of a certain DOM element. Yes, I believe that's possible. Having trouble with anything in particular?

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P99CD/1/ ?

Comment: @jimevans like http://jsfiddle.net/p3sfy/2639/

Comment: @Arun P Johny - kind of like that but it looks like that is to highlight the selected tab? That is not what I want. I want to highlight tab 5 if it shows up period and none of the others.

Comment: @JimEvans it is not highlighting the selected tab.... if you see a class highlighted is added to the second `li` that is why it is highlighted... if you can add the class to the targeted tab then it should work

Comment: @dhana - same thing - not trying to highlight selected tab - but to highlight tab 5 at all times.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the tabs id's or classes why not just do something like:

```
if ($('#yourId').length > 0){ $('#yourId').css('background-colour', '#yourColour');}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want tab 5 all time use css

```
li:nth-child(5){

    background: red !important;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p3sfy/2641/)